# Anonymous user access rights to view for filling a combobox

Tags: xpages

I'm building a form that will be used by anonymous users.  On the form is a combo box that I want to pre-fill so they can pick one of the items.  The items that would fill the combo box are in a database view that is not available to anonymous users.

My initial attempt at doing this was to use a basic Notes form and an agent in the WebQueryOpen event to fill the combo box.  Since that agent ran under my name the combo box got filled in.

When I moved it to xpages, the combo box was empty.  I realized it was because the javascript is running under a non-authenticated user (when I authenticate with my username/password it works correctly).

How do people typically address this issue?

thanks
clem

Comment: Clem, I believe this can be done. You would have a process that retrieves the data using the signers rights, as opposed to the users rights.  There is a specific name for this, which escapes me now, but perhaps someone else can fill in.

Comment: Yep, that is the name I couldn't think of, thanks Paul.

Answer (score 3):

sessionAsSigner is designed to access documents the current user doesn't have access to.

Comment: Many thanks!  That was easy.  I replaced 'session' with 'sessionAsSigner' and it just worked. Thanks!! :-)